# Mobile Safari Keyboard Form Submission

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a basic `form` with a `search input` and a `submit button` within. When focus takes place in the `input`, the keyboard is displayed as expected.  When I press the `button`, the form submit event occurs, in which I call `event.preventDefault()` and instead make an ajax call. However, when I press the **search** button on the keyboard, the keyboard just hides and no submit event occurs.

Why doesn't the form submit when I press search on the keyboard? How can I trigger this event to happen via the keyboard search button?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post code? You shouldn't need to listen for an event.

Comment: Actually you do need to listen to an event if you want to use `ajax`

Comment: Oh gotcha, I normally use the form submit to submit my data via ajax.
you can serialize the form data into json and send that directly. Much easier than having to wire up every input to a model directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyboard search button must be bound to a keypress event and has the `keycode` of `13`.

Basically, listen to `keypress` events and return all calls except for `e.which === 13`

```
$('input').on('keypress', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.which !== 13 ) {
        return;
    }

    // ajax code
}
```